# What are the possible reason for a java.util.concurrent.RejectedExecutionException in a SingleThreadExecutor

Tags: java, multithreading

I created the following executor in a singleton:

```
   final private ExecutorService executor = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor(new ThreadFactory() {
        final ThreadFactory delegate = Executors.defaultThreadFactory();
        public Thread newThread(Runnable paramAnonymousRunnable) { 
            Thread localThread =      this.delegate.newThread(paramAnonymousRunnable);
            localThread.setName("MyTask-" + localThread.getName());
            localThread.setDaemon(XXX.this.daemonThread);
            return localThread;
        }
    });
```

And during the execution of the program, there are a lot calls to this method of the singleton. The calls are done in different threads and maybe at the same time.

```
private void send(final String paramString) {
  try {
      this.executor.execute(new Runnable() {
          public void run() {
              //DO some interesting stuff
          }
      });
  } catch (Exception localException) {
    this.handler.handle(localException);
  }
```

}

And at some point the following stack trace occurred:

```
java.util.concurrent.RejectedExecutionException
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$AbortPolicy.rejectedExecution(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1774)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.reject(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:768)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.execute(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:656)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$DelegatedExecutorService.execute(Executors.java:589)
        at XXXXX.send(XXXX.java:269)
```

Why would the JVM throw such exception?

The `singleThreadExecutor` is backed by a `LinkedBlockingQueue<Runnable>()`.
And  the thread pool wasn't shut down.

The JVM is Oracle JDK 1.6. The singleton was created with Spring,
copied from `java.util.concurrent.Executors`:

```
   public static ExecutorService newSingleThreadExecutor(ThreadFactory threadFactory) {
       return new FinalizableDelegatedExecutorService
           (new ThreadPoolExecutor(1, 1,
                                0L, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS,
                                new LinkedBlockingQueue<Runnable>(),
                                threadFactory));
   }
```

Comment: Does it behave same when you use thread pool instead of single executor?

Comment: Are you 100% positive that the pool was not shutdown? Can you catch the exception and print the state of the executor to confirm that?

Comment: Oracle's JDK ships with source code for the supplied java classes. If your IDE is set up correctly, you should be able to inspect the source to see exactly what is happening at  at ThreadPoolExecutor.java line 656 to make it call `reject()`.

Answer (score 83):

There are two reasons why `execute` would throw a `RejectedExecutionException`

1. The queue is full and you cannot add any more threads
2. The ThreadPool has been shut down

Since you are using a `LinkedBlockingQueue`, the only way I can see this occurring is because you shut down the pool.

Comment: @Choletski you cannot. You will have to create a new `ExecutorService`.

Comment: @JohnVint how about a third? memory under pressure -> a new thread could not be created -> rejected thrown? like [this](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/jdk/file/687fd7c7986d/src/share/classes/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.java#l1368)?

Comment: If you're using an unbounded queue you will see an OOM error (heap space) before that rejection would occur. That line will trigger if the size of the queue is fixed, we cannot add any more elements to the queue and all threads are created & in use.

Answer (score 10):

You might have submitted tasks after calling `executor.shutdown()`. Normally to stop executor they do

```
    executor.shutdown();
    executor.awaitTermination(10, TimeUnit.MINUTES);
```

Comment: Also check for executor.shutdownNow();

Comment: Using shutdownNow() does not prevent the OP exception from happening.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you should use a thread pool instead of using a single executor.

```
    executor = new java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor(30, 30, 60, TimeUnit.SECONDS, new LinkedBlockingQueue<Runnable>(), new ThreadFactory() {
        final AtomicInteger threadNumber = new AtomicInteger( 1 );
        @Override
        public Thread newThread(Runnable r) {
            return new Thread(r, "Thread No : " + threadNumber.getAndIncrement());
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Threads  are not available to execute  the given task.   No linked block queue to que task.

Comment: Please review the [answer] section and [edit] your answer to provide more context.