# java.util.concurrent.RejectedExecutionException:

Tags: java, guava

I was trying to do small poc to understand the difference between Futures.addCallback(future, callback) and Futures.addCallback(future, callback, executor1). As per my understanding, In the latter one the callback should be run by executor1 as specified in the function call.
However while running the below code snippet, I am not able to figure out the reason for the above exception:

```
  class MyTest implements Callable<Integer>{

    int i;
    int j;

    public MyTest(int k, int l) {
        i = k;
        j = l;
    }

    public int getI() {
        return i;
    }

    public void setI(int i) {
        this.i = i;
    }

    public int getJ() {
        return j;
    }

    public void setJ(int j) {
        this.j = j;
    }

    @Override
    public Integer call() throws Exception {
         System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName());  
        System.out.println("Computing.........");
        Thread.currentThread().sleep(5000);
        return i + j;
    }

}


Callable<Integer> call = new MyTest(1,2);
        ListeningExecutorService executor = MoreExecutors.listeningDecorator(Executors.newFixedThreadPool(1));
        ListeningExecutorService executor1 = MoreExecutors.listeningDecorator(Executors.newFixedThreadPool(1));
        //ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(1);
        ListenableFuture<Integer> future = executor.submit(call);
        FutureCallback<Integer> callback = new FutureCallback<Integer>() {

            @Override
            public void onSuccess(Integer result) {
                System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName());   
                System.out.println("Completed Successfully and result is :" + result);

            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Throwable t) {
                System.out.println("Failed");

            }
        };

        Futures.addCallback(future, callback, executor1);
        executor.shutdown();
        executor1.shutdown();
```

Exception log

```
 ????? ??, ???? ?:??:?? ??????? com.google.common.util.concurrent.ExecutionList executeListener
    SEVERE: RuntimeException while executing runnable com.google.common.util.concurrent.Futures$5@37e5f7d7 with executor com.google.common.util.concurrent.MoreExecutors$ListeningDecorator@3d1d9ca7
    java.util.concurrent.RejectedExecutionException: Task com.google.common.util.concurrent.Futures$5@37e5f7d7 rejected from java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor@39220f5b[Terminated, pool size = 0, active threads = 0, queued tasks = 0, completed tasks = 0]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$AbortPolicy.rejectedExecution(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:2047)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.reject(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:823)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.execute(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1369)
        at com.google.common.util.concurrent.MoreExecutors$ListeningDecorator.execute(MoreExecutors.java:484)
        at com.google.common.util.concurrent.ExecutionList.executeListener(ExecutionList.java:156)
        at com.google.common.util.concurrent.ExecutionList.execute(ExecutionList.java:145)
        at com.google.common.util.concurrent.ListenableFutureTask.done(ListenableFutureTask.java:91)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:384)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.set(FutureTask.java:233)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:274)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Comment: Text for the exception?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What are the possible reason for a java.util.concurrent.RejectedExecutionException in a SingleThreadExecutor](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19003430/what-are-the-possible-reason-for-a-java-util-concurrent-rejectedexecutionexcepti)

Comment: No exception for me either. Granted, because he left out what "MyTest" is, I just faked it with my own Callable

Comment: Have updated question, One thing to notice that on uncommenting Thread.currentThread().sleep(5000); from call method that exception does not come up.

Comment: @Jens  I think problem is occuring in different context and it is somehow related with wrong usage of method Futures.addCallback(future, callback, executor1)

Answer (score 3):

Exception is throw because in you code snippet `executor1` was stopped by call `executor1.shutdown();` Try comment out this line and exception gone.

If you want to shutdown executor after `callback` completes execute shutdown inside callback code

```
  FutureCallback<Integer> callback = new FutureCallback<Integer>() {

        @Override
        public void onSuccess(Integer result) {
            System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName());   
            System.out.println("Completed Successfully and result is :" + result);
            executor1.shutdown(); // shutdown it here! 
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Throwable t) {
            System.out.println("Failed");
            executor1.shutdown(); // shutdown it here! 
        }
    };
    Futures.addCallback(future, callback, executor1);
    executor.shutdown();
    // executor1.shutdown(); // do not stop it here!
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: answer is simple - do not call shutdown executor1 to prevent exception.