# java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$AbortPolicy.rejectedExecution

Tags: android

```
Fatal Exception: java.util.concurrent.RejectedExecutionException
Task java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask@52a169d rejected 
from g.j.d.p.r.v0.c$a@649b174[Terminated, pool size = 0, active threads = 0, queued tasks = 
0, completed tasks = 4668]
```

This is an issue I came across from the crashlytics of my project. Help me figure out the solution here.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19003430/what-are-the-possible-reason-for-a-java-util-concurrent-rejectedexecutionexcepti, can help you

Comment: The fact that you have `Task` and obsfucated code `g.j.d.p.r.v0` is a tell-tail sign its firebase related.

Comment: @MarkKeen Thanks. This looks like the firebase related issue. But, what can be the possible reason behind this?

Comment: Probably, looking at the error the Executor has been shutdown, but a `ScheduledFutureTask` has been been posted to it via `schedule`, or something of that nature.